# How do you return function results to a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Seems easy but I can't figure it out, how would you return the results from a function that's being imported to a component?
I get the correct results when i console log them from the .then() but can't seem to return them to the component.

example:

functions.js

```
export const getFeatures = (e) => {
    let features = Client.getEntries({
        content_type: '###',
        'fields.type': `${e}`
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.items;
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

Component.js

```
import {getFeatures} from './functions.js'

const App = () => {
   let x = getFeatures('home');
   console.log(x)  

   return ( ... )                 


// expecting the array response [{},{},{}, .. etc], but getting undefined instead


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getFeatures('home')` will return `undefined` instead of `response.items` in your code.

Try this:

```js
// functions.js
export const getFeatures = async (e) => {
    const resp = await Client.getEntries({
        content_type: '###',
        'fields.type': `${e}`
    })
    return resp.items;
}
```

```js
// App.js
import {getFeatures} from './functions.js'

const App = () => {
    getFeatures('home').then(x => {
        console.log(x);
        // do something else
    });

    return ( ... )                 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getFeatures` doesn't return anything, you should change it to return its promise:

```
export const getFeatures = (e) => {
    return Client.getEntries({
        content_type: '###',
        'fields.type': `${e}`
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.items;
    })
    .catch(console.error)
}
```

then at App add a features state, that will get updated when you call `getFeatures` on mount stage called by `useEffect`:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {getFeatures} from './functions.js'

const App = () => {
   // create a features state
   const [features, setFeatures] = useState([])
   
   // on mount call 'getFeatures'
   useEffect(() => {
    getFeatures('home')
      .then(setFeatures) // chain returned promise and pass setFeatures to update features
     
   }, []) // add empty array to tell to run the code on mount only

   // do some mapping with features, this is for example purpose
   // remember to add an unique key to each feature
   return ( features.map(feature => {
     return <div key={feature.id}>{feature.name}: {feature.realease}</div>
    }))                 
}
```